# Reserved characters and symbols in mvc 4 controller name

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create something like this

```
  public class business-economyController : Controller
    {
```

But the "-" symbol creates an issue if used in the name of controller and the VS IDE automatically renames it to something like this

```
  public class business_economyController : Controller
    {
```

Notice the "-" replaced with "_" character.

It should be a trivial task and not affect the url but may be I am missing something. 
My question is,
Is it impossible to use such characters in controller name?
if no, how to use them in the controller name ?

Edit:
My objective here is to allow a hyphen in the url. I want the url to something like http://www.xxxxxx.com/business-economy

However, as MVC tries to resolve the controller class name, it fail here. It is possible to give a specific name to action by adding attribute but not controller. Is there any way where can I have a "-" sign in the url specifically in the controller token ?

Comment: C# specification does not allow this. But... Why do you need to call the controller like that? Instead use full CamelCase... `businessEconomyController` and use `RouteConfig` to specify the desired url.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not allow a hyphen in the class name as per the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx).

So in short, this is not a MVC issue, but a C# specification.